# Android if else block wont run

Tags: android, if-statement, android-activity

I have an app on a startup that performs 3 checks (everything happens in a separate file called "Application"): first for an internet connection, then for the internet connection type, and lastly, for the apps permission to start main activity.

All 3 checks pass correctly, however, on the last pass I get in a string value "False", which is fine, but in the splash screen when I want to check that value, it does not work. I did set if block if the value is false to launch another acitivty, but it does not, it just ignores that block.

Here is the code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setFullScreen();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity_init);
    if(APP.connectionCheck(InitActivity.this) == "TRUE"){
        JSONObject JOBJC = APP.getJSON(APP.defaultUrl());
        String result = APP.checkPermission(JOBJC);
        if(result=="false"){
            Intent i = new Intent(this,app.pcg.notation.Notation.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }else if(result=="true"){

        }
    }else{
        Intent i = new Intent(this,app.pcg.notation.Notation.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: `==` compares Strings Refrences(Memory Location) AND `.equals()` compare String Value.                              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: The real question is: why are you returning a `String` from your methods when it seems as if a `boolean` would be more appropiate?

Comment: well , what difference does it make ?

Comment: `boolean` can only assume the values `true` or `false`, which seems to be exactly what you need. `String` on the other hand is just a series of characters, open for interpretation. Using `String` in this context is like using a text input field in a "yes/no" question in a web form instead of a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Change to this `result.equals("false") or result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")` . You can not compare string using `==` Operator.

Do it same for else part .

`result.equals("true") or result.equalsIgnoreCase("true")`

**Edit Code**

```
if(APP.connectionCheck(InitActivity.this).equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
        JSONObject JOBJC = APP.getJSON(APP.defaultUrl());
        String result = APP.checkPermission(JOBJC);
        if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
            Intent i = new Intent(this,app.pcg.notation.Notation.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }else if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){

        }
    }else{
        Intent i = new Intent(this,app.pcg.notation.Notation.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare `String`s with `==` in Java. Use `String.equals()` instead.

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

String comparisons MUST be done with `.equals()`. Using `==` for objects compares the pointer value (i.e. is it the same object?) rather than the value.

So, `if(APP.connectionCheck(InitActivity.this).equals("TRUE"))` ...

Comment: thnx for that , i work a lot in php ,so sometimes i do stupid mistakes like that one

Answer (score 1):

always use **equals();** while you are comparing two strings

because `==` operator checks reference to the objects,
while `equals()` checks its value.

you will get proper result

```
if( APP.connectionCheck(InitActivity.this).equals("true"))
{
}
```

or

```
if( APP.connectionCheck(InitActivity.this).equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
{
}
```